# Fast way to select and delete all photos on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

[One way](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-delete-all-photos-from-iphone?r=AU&IR=T) to delete all photos from an iPhone is to go to the bottom photos in an album, tap 'Select' in the top right of screen, press the bottom right photo and without lifting your finger, move your finger to the top left of screen, where it will continue to scroll up while selecting photos.

The problem is, this selects photos at a rate of about 200 photos per 10 seconds. I have 25,000 photos, so I will need to sit there holding my finger in exactly the right place for 20 minutes.

How can I delete all photos from an iPhone album quickly and efficiently? (i.e. immediately)

Answer (score 1):

1. Click 'Select'
2. Move your finger from the bottom-right most photo and move your photo up to the top left of screen (so the screen starts scrolling up and selecting photos)
3. Here's the important step, with your other hand, tap the top left of screen (above where your finger on your other hand is). It might take a few tries but it will eventually speed all the way to the top of your photos only taking 1-2 seconds, whilst selecting all the photos along the way.

It's a little tricky, but very much worth it.

Comment: What helped me speed up the selection is not tapping, but swiping with the other hand. Swiping works perfectly while you hold your finger to select photos.